# How to set the delimiter, Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, csv, collation

I am wondering what the delimiter from this .csv file is. I am trying to import the .csv via the COPY FROM Statement, but somehow it throws always an error. When I change the delimiter to E'\t' it throws an error. When I change the delimiter to '|' it throws a different error. I have been trying to import a silly .csv file for 3 days and I cannot achieve a success. **I really need your help**. Here is my .csv file: [Download here, please](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=02174413852838197235)

My code on postgresql looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE movie
(
 imdib  varchar NOT NULL,
 name varchar NOT NULL,
 year integer,
 rating float ,
 votes integer,
 runtime varchar  ,
 directors varchar ,
 actors varchar ,
genres varchar
);
```

MY COPY Statement:

```
COPY movie FROM '/home/max/Schreibtisch/imdb_top100t_2015-06-18.csv' (DELIMITER E'\t', FORMAT CSV, NULL '', ENCODING 'UTF8');
```

When I use `SHOW SERVER_ENCODING` it says "UTF8". But why the hell can't postgre read the datas from the columns? I really do not get it. I use Ubuntu 64 bit, the .csv file has all the permissions it needs, postgresql has also. Please help me.
These are my errors:

> ERROR:  missing data for column "name"
>   CONTEXT:  COPY movie, line 1: "tt0468569,The Dark Knight,2008,9,1440667,152 mins.,Christopher Nolan,Christian Bale|Heath Ledger|Aar..."

********** Error **********

> ERROR: missing data for column "name"
>   SQL state: 22P04
>   Context: COPY movie, line 1: "tt0468569,The Dark Knight,2008,9,1440667,152 mins.,Christopher Nolan,Christian Bale|Heath Ledger|Aar..."

Comment: Well, I determined it, since it is a .csv file it is comma seperated. But the problem is, after the columns there are 5 commas, ",,,,," and this after every single row. So therefore postgre says "error extra data after last expected column" how can i Solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

Use this code instead it is working fine on Linux as well on windows

```
\COPY movie(imdib,name,year,rating,votes,runtime,directors,actors,genres) FROM 'D:\test.csv' WITH DELIMITER '|' CSV HEADER;
```

and one more thing insert header in your csv file like shown below:

```
imdib|name|year|rating|votes|runtime|directors|actors|genres
tt0111161|The Shawshank Redemption|1994|9.3|1468273|142 mins.|Frank Darabont|Tim Robbins|Morgan Freeman
```

and use single byte delimiter like ',','|' etc.

Hope this will work for you ..!

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
COPY movie (imdib,name,year,rating,votes,runtime,directors,actors,genres) 
    FROM 'imdb_top100t_2015-06-18.csv' 
    WITH (format csv, header false, delimiter E'\t', NULL '');
```

Unfortunately the file is invalid because on line 12011 the column `year` contains the value `2015 Video` and thus the import fails because this can't be converted to an integer. And then further down (line 64155) there is an invalid value `NA` for the rating which can't be converted to a float and then one more for the votes.

But if you create the table with all varchar columns the above command worked for me.

Comment: THank you, it worked me for me on WINDOWS, but not ubuntu. Do you have an idea ?